# Dynamically set name attribute of input field in loop with AlpineJS

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'd like to set the `name` attribute of hidden input fields in a loop with AlpineJS. I've tried `x-bind:name` but that doesn't work.

I think this doesn't work because of the `x-model` in how todos are added:

```
<input x-model="todoText" type="text">

<button x-on:click.prevent="addTodo('new', todoText)">
    Add
</button>
```

How can I make the below work so that the index key in the `todos` array is set to the `todoSingle.id` value?

```
<template x-for="todoSingle in todoArray" :key="todoSingle.id">
    <input type="hidden" name="todos[todoSingle.id][id]" x-model="todoSingle.id">
    <input type="hidden" name="todos[todoSingle.id][type]" x-model="todoSingle.type">
    <input type="hidden" name="todos[todoSingle.id][description]" x-model="todoSingle.description">
</template>
```

**Update**

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/eskimo1/pen/KKzWzEm). If you add a todo, then go back to the input field and type, you'll see that on every keyup the same todo is added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `x-bind:name` with a template string:

```html
<input type="hidden" x-bind:name="`todos[${todoSingle.id}][id]`" x-model="todoSingle.id">
<input type="hidden" x-bind:name="`todos[${todoSingle.id}][type]`" x-model="todoSingle.type">
<input type="hidden" x-bind:name="`todos[${todoSingle.id}][description]`" x-model="todoSingle.description">
```

See the fixed [Codepen](https://codepen.io/hugodf/pen/xxVqOeb)

Comment: As indicated in the original question `x-bind:name` doesn't work. What happens is that on every keyup in the input field the todo is added. I've added the input field and the button that adds the todo in my question.

Comment: I also get `Can't find variable todoSingle` and `Can't find variable todos`

Comment: Do you have this running in a codepen? Or the full component code

Comment: I'll create one, just a few minutes

Comment: Codepen added to the question.

Comment: Answer updated and have forked the codepen to a working state https://codepen.io/hugodf/pen/xxVqOeb