# Laravel merge arrays into one array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am sending 4 arrays to my controller that they need to combine before I can store them to database, here is how they're look like:

```
array:4 [▼
  "from" => array:7 [▼
    0 => "8:00"
    1 => null
    2 => null
    3 => null
    4 => null
    5 => null
    6 => null
  ]
  "to" => array:7 [▼
    0 => "21:00"
    1 => null
    2 => null
    3 => null
    4 => null
    5 => null
    6 => null
  ]
  "closed" => array:6 [▼
    0 => "on"
    1 => "on"
    2 => "on"
    3 => "on"
    4 => "on"
    5 => "on"
  ]
  "day_id" => array:7 [▼
    0 => "a0275acb-c6e5-428f-8589-da0644c1f42e"
    1 => "9a8d2dc5-fbe5-4a93-a279-2c6a90781777"
    2 => "84d74f04-3728-4314-a6e7-8710cecaa911"
    3 => "79ef140a-5de5-4b27-a286-9893cbac820e"
    4 => "6d0b2858-ff96-46ce-ae1b-665c3ee353aa"
    5 => "38225fe6-3bce-4ee9-bad8-c7f6cacc4854"
    6 => "28cef2be-1ff6-4e80-b322-a208f4838391"
  ]
]
```

> As you might notice `closed` array is less by 1 value as the checkbox was unchecked, so this one is vary between no value (if none are check) to 7 values (if all of them are checked)

Anyway, I need to make this arrays to something like this:

```
array:7 [▼
  "finaldata" => array:4 [▼
    from => "8:00"
    to => "21:00"
    closed => off
    day_id => "a0275acb-c6e5-428f-8589-da0644c1f42e"
  ],
 "finaldata" => array:4 [▼
    from => null
    to => null
    closed => on
    day_id => "9a8d2dc5-fbe5-4a93-a279-2c6a90781777"
  ],
  // and so on...
]
```

If I can get such result then I'll be able to loop and store this data into my database.

#### Code

```
$schedules = [];
$schedules['from'] = $request->input('from');
$schedules['to'] = $request->input('to');
$schedules['closed'] = $request->input('closed');
$schedules['day_id'] = $request->input('day_id');
dd($schedules); // returning my results above (on top)

foreach($schedules as $schedule) {
  $days = new WorkDays;
  //...
  $days->save();
}
```

#### Question

**How can I get such result as I shared to store my data?**

## Update

`blade`

```
<div class="mt-4">
    <div x-data="handler()">
        <x-jet-label value="Schedule" />
        <table class="itable align-middle w-full">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    <th>Day</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>Closed</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <template x-for="(field, index) in {{$days}}" :key="index">
                    <tr>
                        <td x-text="field.name"></td>
                        <td>
                            <x-jet-input x-model="field.from" type="text" name="from[]" />
                            <x-jet-input x-model="field.id" type="hidden" value="field" name="day_id[]"/>
                        </td>
                        <td><x-jet-input x-model="field.to" type="text" name="to[]" /></td>
                        <td><input x-model="field.closed" class="form-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="closed[]" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
        function handler() {
            return {
                fields: []
            }
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

## Update 2

based on `iCoders` answer this is what i get, which is good but the ones with unchecked checkbox will not have `closed` variable `array 0 and 6`.

```
"data" => array:7 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "from" => "54"
      "day_id" => "a0275acb-c6e5-428f-8589-da0644c1f42e"
      "to" => "474"
    ]
    1 => array:4 [▼
      "from" => null
      "day_id" => "9a8d2dc5-fbe5-4a93-a279-2c6a90781777"
      "to" => null
      "closed" => "on"
    ]
    2 => array:4 [▼
      "from" => null
      "day_id" => "84d74f04-3728-4314-a6e7-8710cecaa911"
      "to" => null
      "closed" => "on"
    ]
    3 => array:4 [▼
      "from" => null
      "day_id" => "79ef140a-5de5-4b27-a286-9893cbac820e"
      "to" => null
      "closed" => "on"
    ]
    4 => array:4 [▼
      "from" => null
      "day_id" => "6d0b2858-ff96-46ce-ae1b-665c3ee353aa"
      "to" => null
      "closed" => "on"
    ]
    5 => array:4 [▼
      "from" => null
      "day_id" => "38225fe6-3bce-4ee9-bad8-c7f6cacc4854"
      "to" => null
      "closed" => "on"
    ]
    6 => array:3 [▼
      "from" => "67565"
      "day_id" => "28cef2be-1ff6-4e80-b322-a208f4838391"
      "to" => "6567"
    ]
```

Comment: You need to tie your form controls together so that you know which checkbox is not checked. You can do this by adding an index to your form control's names. I just answered a question like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64707394/attach-images-to-product-variants-when-creating-a-new-product-laravel/64707895#64707895

Comment: I think you would have to fix how you send the request data on the frontend. The way you are doing it, you have no way of knowing to which of the registers correspond the elements of the `closed` array .

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I've updated my question would you mind point me what should I do?

Comment: @bassxzero sorry but I couldn't make relative connection between your answer there and my question here, it didn't help

Comment: @mafortis.updated answer

Comment: In your php's foreach loop just use `isset($value['closed'])` to see if the value is set. If it's not set just set it to `off`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know much usage about new component in laravel 8 but usually common idea is

```
@foreach($days as $key=>$value)
 <tr>
                        <td x-text="field.name"></td>
                        <td>
                            <x-jet-input x-model="field.from" type="text" name="data[{{$key}}][from]" />
                            <x-jet-input x-model="field.id" type="hidden" value="field" name="data[{{$key}}][day_id]"/>
                        </td>
                        <td><x-jet-input x-model="field.to" type="text" name="data[{{$key}}][to]" /></td>
                        <td><input x-model="field.closed" class="form-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="data[{{$key}}][closed]" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    @endforeach
```

Then in controller if you dd($request->data) you get merged data

**Updated**

As per another question answer [Dynamically set name attribute of input field in loop with AlpineJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63574576/dynamically-set-name-attribute-of-input-field-in-loop-with-alpinejs)
You need to use `x-bind:name` with a template string:

```
 <template x-for="(field, index) in {{$days}}" :key="index">
                    <tr>
                        <td x-text="field.name"></td>
                        <td>
                            <x-jet-input x-model="field.from" type="text" x-bind:name="`data[${index}][from]`/>
                            <x-jet-input x-model="field.id" type="hidden" value="field" x-bind:name="`data[${index}][day_id]`"/>
                        </td>
                        <td><x-jet-input x-model="field.to" type="text" x-bind:name="`data[${index}][to]` /></td>
                        <td><input x-model="field.closed" class="form-checkbox" type="checkbox" x-bind:name="`data[${index}][closed]` /></td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
```

**Update2:**

```
<input x-model="field.closed" class="form-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="data[{{$key}}][closed]" @click="$event.target.value = $event.target.checked ? '1' : '2'"/>
```

Comment: Thank you it return results very good but, it has small issue I will update my question so you can see it\

Comment: oaky will check

Comment: still no have `closed` `0 => array:3 [▼
      "from" => "325"
      "day_id" => "a0275acb-c6e5-428f-8589-da0644c1f42e"
      "to" => "352"
    ]`

Comment: @mafortisif checkbox is not clicked then key wont available in laravel.you may need to add validation for that

Comment: How do I add that?

Comment: @mafortis.refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50489519/how-to-pass-checkbox-value-0-if-not-checked-and-1-if-checked-using-array-laravel/50490572

Comment: Thank you it's solved from controller. `(isset($schedule['closed'])) ? true : false;`

Answer (score 0):

Change your blade to something like this.

```html
<template x-for="(field, index) in {{$days}}" :key="index">
    <tr>
        <td x-text="field.name"></td>
        <td>
            <x-jet-input x-model="field.from" type="text" name="finaldata[{{$loop->iteration}}]['from']" />
            <x-jet-input x-model="field.id" type="hidden" value="field" name="finaldata[{{$loop->iteration}}]['day_id']"/>
        </td>
        <td><x-jet-input x-model="field.to" type="text" name="finaldata[{{$loop->iteration}}]['to']" /></td>
        <td><input x-model="field.closed" class="form-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="finaldata[{{$loop->iteration}}]['closed']" /></td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: `Undefined variable: loop`

Comment: Wait is that `x-for` loop directive for your JS framework?

Comment: it's laravel 8 uses alpine js

Comment: Yeah you're looping in your JS framework so this won't work. How do you get the index number you are on in your for loop?

Comment: days in in my table are dynamic (which I only loop them, the rest are static as user fills) so the `index` is based on `days` array. `(field, index) in {{$days}}`